# Characteristic time for changes in the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Just a short query, given an electron at rest at the origin in the presence of a  magnetic field whose magnitude is constant but whose direction is rotating around a cone at constant angular velocity $\omega$:
$$\vec{B}(t) = B_0[\sin \alpha \cos (\omega t)\hat{x} + \sin \alpha \sin (\omega t) \hat{y} + \cos \alpha \hat{z}],$$ where the corresponding Hamiltonian is $$H(t) = \frac{e}{m}\vec{B} \cdot \vec{S} = \frac{\hbar \omega_1}{2} \dbinom{\cos \alpha~~~e^{-i \omega t}\sin \alpha}{e^{i \omega t}\sin \alpha~~~-\cos \alpha}.$$
It is considered in a text I am using that the *characteristic time for changes in the Hamiltonian* is $\frac{1}{\omega}$, why is this the chosen characteristic time for change of the Hamiltonian? Is this standard?

Comment: The Hamiltonian oscillates with period $2 \pi / \omega$. So there's a timescale of $1/\omega$ here, i.e. a quantity with dimensions of time that relates to how the Hamiltonian is changing.

Comment: @knzhou Yes I understand that. But the *characteristic time* is not just any measurement of time, it is the time taken for something to change appreciably. For example the characteristic time for wave functions to change appreciably is given  as $t \approx \frac{\hbar}{\Delta E}$. I'm asking why is this particular time considered to be a time where the Hamiltonian changes appreciably?

Comment: Would you agree that the Hamiltonian 'changed appreciably' after time $\pi/\omega$, since this is the time it takes for the transverse field to flip sign?

Comment: @knzhou Yes exactly that's what I would have expected it to be. That is what is confusing. Why not use that?

Comment: Characteristic times are always defined just 'up to an order of magnitude'. After all, you can't make a strong argument for why its' $\pi/\omega$ rather than, say, $2\pi/\omega$ or $\pi/2\omega$, so might as well throw out the prefactors and call it $1/\omega$.

Comment: It's the same way with radioactive decay, where the characteristic time is the time to decay to $1/e$. Why not $1/2$ or $1/4$? It doesn't really matter.

Comment: @knzhou Oh okay thanks for discussion, that makes sense.